Configuring custom cache invalidation for MyBatis xml mapper
I have a basic CrUD flow in my MyBatis mapper.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="office.dao.mapper.PersonMapper">
    <resultMap id="person" type="office.dao.entity.Person">
        <result column="ID" property="id" jdbcType="INTEGER"/>
        <result column="NAME" property="name" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
        <result column="FLAG" property="flag" jdbcType="TINYINT"/>
        <result column="CREATED_BY" property="createdBy" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
        <result column="CREATED_DATE" property="createdDate" jdbcType="TIMESTAMP"/>
    </resultMap>

    <insert id="insert" parameterType="office.dao.entity.Person" keyColumn="id" keyProperty="id" useGeneratedKeys="true">
        INSERT INTO PERSON(NAME, FLAG, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE)
        VALUES(#{name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{flag,jdbcType=TINYINT}, #{createdBy, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{createdDate, jdbcType=TIMESTAMP})
    </insert>

    <select id="selectAll" resultMap="person">
        SELECT * FROM PERSON
    </select>

    <select id="selectAllByFlag" resultMap="person">
        SELECT * FROM PERSON
        WHERE FLAG = #{flag,jdbcType=TINYINT}
    </select>

    <select id="selectAllByName" resultMap="person">
        SELECT * FROM PERSON
        WHERE NAME = #{name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
    </select>

    <insert id="updateName">
        UPDATE PERSON
        SET NAME = #{name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
        WHERE ID = #{id,jdbcType=INTEGER}
    </insert>

    <insert id="updateFlag">
        UPDATE PERSON
        SET FLAG = #{flag,jdbcType=TINYINT}
        WHERE ID = #{id,jdbcType=INTEGER}
    </insert>

    <delete id="delete">
        DELETE FROM PERSON
        WHERE ID = #{id,jdbcType=INTEGER}
    </delete>
</mapper>

I want to cache the result of the following methods: selectAll, selectAllByFlag and selectAllByName but I want their caches to be invalidated and purged when other method of this mapper has been called: insert, updateName, updateFlag, or delete.
My problem is that I only see example of MyBatis configuration that are time-based, that is, the cache will be invalidated if it expired after the configured duration. Is my requirements doable using MyBatis configuration? I saw the mapper attribute flushCache that I can set but I am not sure the scope on which if will flush the cache i.e. will it flush the cache if the containing mapper only or the entire application? I could manually implement saving and clearing a cache implementation before calling the mapper methods if my requirement is currently not supported.

You just need to add <cache /> to the mapper, basically. "All results from select statements in the mapped statement file will be cached." "All insert, update and delete statements in the mapped statement file will flush the cache." https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#cache You might want to change the size if the default 1024 is too small or too big.
